# How can I realize delete method in Gridview?When the adapter is not in fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gridview

I did it before when I wrote the adapter class as an inner class of the fragment. But I am wondering if it is possible to write the adapter as an independent class?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.build(getItem(position).toString());
    deleteView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
    deleteView.setVisibility(isShowDelete ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    deleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItemInShared(items.get(position));
            items.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

All the search results of google are `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but the adapter is not in the adapter class. 
Any solutions?

Another notifyDataSetChanged() wored.

GridViewAdapter.java

```
 public void setIsShowDelete(boolean isShowDelete) {
    this.isShowDelete = isShowDelete;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

called by Fragment
    g_adapter.setIsShowDelete(false);

Comment: which adapter are you extending ?

Comment: BaseDynamicGridAdapter it is a project in Github    .BaseDynamicGridAdapter extends AbstractDynamicGridAdapter . AbstractDynamicGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,It is possible to write your adapter as a different class.All you have to do is to create a constructor for your adapter class and pass your arraylist from your fragment to adapter class constructor as a parameter.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //your arraylist here
    MyAdapter myadp=new MyAdpater(arraylilst);
     listview.setAdapter(myadp);
        myadp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      }
```

In your adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {
   ArrayList<String> items;
    public void Myadapter(ArrayList<String> items)
     {
    this.items=items;
    }
   //override methods

     @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup         
       parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) {
    convertView =        
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
      holder.build(getItem(position).toString());
      deleteView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_markView);
     deleteView.setVisibility(isShowDelete ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    deleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        removeItemInShared(items.get(position));
        items.remove(position);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
return convertView;
}
```

Hope this helps.Happy Coding!!

Comment: holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
      holder.build(getItem(position).toString());

Comment: insteada of using the controls directly,you create a ViewHolder class and put all the controls you used in your xml under this.By creating an object of this class you can instantiate the controls.

Comment: Sorry for asking that stupid, I had tried to fix the bug all hours. And didn't  notice I wrote the part of code

Comment: it's better to use ViewHolder but there is no specific rule that you need to use it for sure.

Comment: public classs ViewHolder{ TextView t1;EditText e1; }  now you can use this like viewholder.e1=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id._id);

Comment: I already did this, but it didn't work. The notifyDataSetChanged() didn't work.

Comment: I did "create a constructor for your adapter class and pass your arraylist "

Comment: you need to call notifydatasetchanged() method for the instance of MyAdapter class.